# Check user permissions in Electron on Mac

Tags: macos, permissions, app-store, electron

I've tried to submit a build to the app store but I ran into the following problem:

They are saying that some menu items do nothing. These menu actions are open and save file which reads and writes files to the file system. I figured out that the App Review Team runs my app on a guest account where the user has no permission to access the file system. Due to the permissions, the dialog prompt doesn't show up.

Is there a way to check the user permissions in [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) that I can disable the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself. The entitlement files for my app were missing.

You can include them with:

```
electron-osx-sign App.app --entitlements=build/parent.entitlements --entitlements-inherit=build/child.entitlements
```

My entitlements files are looking like the following:

`parent.entitlements`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.music.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

`child.entitlements`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

For more [information](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-osx-sign/blob/master/bin/electron-osx-sign-usage.txt).

Comment: Bit unrelated: We were recording audio using `sox` and spawning a child process. It worked when running `electron .` but not when compiling the app for mac. Adding the entitlements and `com.apple.security.device.audio-input` solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the easiest way would be to attempt to do something that requires elevated permissions and then catch the error if you can't do it.

For example you say you are performing "reads and writes files to the file system" - so just try and do a test write on the path/file as you need. e.g.

```
fs.writeFile(YOUR_PATH, 'testperms', { flag: 'wx' }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // handle/disable your menu items 
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a really good idea but it comes a bit too late. I've found another solution based on the entitlement files which were missing. I will write an answer for this.